# How do I print a new line after GNU-make's "--print-directory" output is displayed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The `--print-directory` [option](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_5.html#SEC54) for GNU make will print directory traversal messages like so:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/users/clachanc/directory'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/users/clachanc/directory'
make[1]: Entering directory '/users/clachanc/directory2'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/users/clachanc/directory2'
```

I would like to separate these messages so that they are easier to read, like so:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/users/clachanc/directory'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/users/clachanc/directory'

make[1]: Entering directory '/users/clachanc/directory2'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/users/clachanc/directory2'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to edit the source code, or else post-process the output (piping it through sed or similar) to add the newline.

If you want to edit the source code, in modern versions of GNU make you should look in `output.c` (in the GNU make source) to add an extra `\n` to the end of the format line for these messages.

To use sed, do something like:

```
make ... | sed '/^make.*: Leaving directory/a\ '
```

Comment: Piping the output through sed worked perfectly. Thank you!